Web scraping- Attribute Error Nonetype on findall()
I am having trouble regarding this snippet of code where I am consistently getting an AttributeError
def get_product_price(soup):
    main_price_span = soup.find("span",attrs={
        'class': "a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay"
    })
    price_spans = main_price_span.findAll("span")
    for span in price_spans:
        price = span.text.strip().replace(',','')
        try:
            return float(price)
        except ValueError:
            print("Value obtained for price could not be found")
            exit()

    price_spans = main_price_span.findAll("span")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

I tried changing the attribute to something else but it still gives me the same error. I tried it using different links but I am still getting the same results. I am trying to display the price of the amazon products in my table. I am new to web scraping.
